# adapter not set to listview android

Tags: android, listview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My adapter is not set to listview. There is no error in the logcat and there is data in the list.

```
        lv = (ListView) vi.findViewById(R.id.list);


        // Get a reference to our posts
        final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference().child("chatusers");
        urlList = new ArrayList<List>();

        final ProgressDialog Dialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        Dialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        Dialog.show();
// Attach a listener to read the data at our posts reference
        ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String chatwithname, foodname, foodimage;
                for (DataSnapshot messageSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {


                    Log.d("chatwithname", messageSnapshot.child("chatwithname").getValue().toString());
                    chatwithname = messageSnapshot.child("chatwithname").getValue().toString();
                    foodname = messageSnapshot.child("foodname").getValue().toString();

                    foodimage = messageSnapshot.child("foodimage").getValue().toString();

                    Log.d("chatusers", chatwithname + "" + foodname + "" + foodimage);
                    List list1 = Arrays.asList(chatwithname, foodname, foodimage);
                    urlList.add(list1);
                    Log.d("urlList", urlList.toString());
                }
                chatusersAdapter  chat = new chatusersAdapter(
                        getActivity(),urlList);

                lv.setAdapter(chat);
                Dialog.hide();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                System.out.println("The read failed: " + databaseError.getCode());
            }
        });
```

My adapter class

```
    public class chatusersAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<List> {
    private final Context context;
    List<List> DialogList = new ArrayList<List>();


    public chatusersAdapter(Context context, List<List> values) {
        super(context, R.layout.chatusers_list, values);
        this.context = context;
        this.DialogList = values;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        Log.d("getview","getview");

        final int i=position;

        List dialog = DialogList.get(i);
        Log.d("chatwithusername", dialog.get(0).toString());

        ViewHolder holder;
        ImageView imageViews;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflator = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            convertView = layoutInflator.inflate(R.layout.chatusers_list, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.chat_with_user = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.chat_with_user);
            holder.item_name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_name);

            holder.img_product = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_product);


            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }

        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        holder.chat_with_user.setText(dialog.get(0).toString());
        holder.item_name.setText(dialog.get(1).toString());
        Glide.with(context).load(dialog.get(2).toString()).into(holder.img_product);

        return convertView;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        Log.d("asifa",String.valueOf(DialogList.size()));
        return DialogList.size();
    }
    static class ViewHolder {

        ImageView img_product;
        TextView item_name;
        TextView chat_with_user;
    }


}
```

The list is displaying in the log, there is data in the list but its not setting to listview. The problem is here

```
`chatusersAdapter chat = new chatusersAdapter( getActivity(),urlList); lv.setAdapter(chat);`
```

The adapter is not called.
Can someone please help?

Comment: You should try setting some breakpoints to check if onDataChange is really being called, it it's entering the for loop, if urlList is actually being populated with data, if getView is being called inside your adapter. That's what I'd do.

Comment: urlList is populated. but getView is not called.

Answer (score 0):

you should implement `getCount()` method of your adapter like this:

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return DialogList.size();
}
```

Comment: No its not working even after adding the getCount method. The problem is here  chatusersAdapter chat = new chatusersAdapter(
                        getActivity(),urlList);

                lv.setAdapter(chat);